# duplicate key in a PostgreSQL index

Tags: postgresql, indexing, unique

I want to move my OwnCloud database to a new server, but the operation fails during restore.

```
pg_restore: [archive program (db)] COPY failed for table "oc_storages": ERROR: value of a duplicate key breaks unique constraint "storages_id_index"
DETAIL: The key "(id) = (local :: / var / www / owncloud_data /)" already exists.
```

Indeed, a simple query on the oc_sorages database shows that there is a duplicate.

```
ocl=# select  * from oc_storages where id ~* 'owncloud_data';
               id               | numeric_id | available | last_checked 
--------------------------------+------------+-----------+--------------
 local::/var/www/owncloud_data/ |        491 |         1 |             
 local::/var/www/owncloud_data/ |        838 |         1 |             
(2 rows)
```

but at the same time, postgresql managed to create an index for this table based on the id (storages_id_index). How is it possible that PostgreSQL accepts this duplicate in this table?

```
ocl=# SELECT indexname, indexdef FROM pg_indexes WHERE tablename = 'oc_storages';
     indexname     |                                      indexdef                                       
-------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 oc_storages_pkey  | CREATE UNIQUE INDEX oc_storages_pkey ON public.oc_storages USING btree (numeric_id)
 storages_id_index | CREATE UNIQUE INDEX storages_id_index ON public.oc_storages USING btree (id)
(2 rows)
```

What to do to get out of this impasse: delete one of the two values? which ?

Thanks in advance.

Ernest.

Comment: What were you doing? restoring into a freshly allocated database? -> Check the encoding/collation.

Comment: Have you tried [Reindex](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-reindex.html) on the table /indexes?

Answer (score 1):

There are usually two explanation for this:

- Hardware problems leading to data corruption. Then remove conflicting rows manually, export the database and import it into a newly created cluster to get rid of potential lurking data corruption.
- You upgraded the C library on the operating system and the collations changed, corrupting the index. Then remove conflicting rows manually and `REINDEX` the indexes with string columns.

Comment: the problem occurred on my Owncloud 10.0.3 and posgresql 9.4 instance. I arbitrarily deleted one of the duplicates and everything is working fine. Thanks !

Comment: PostgreSQL 9.4, probably on an old system... I am not surprised.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of those semantic annoyances I have with Postgres, but creating a UNIQUE INDEX on a table does not actually add an enforced table constraint.

You need to explicitly add each constraint USING the created index, e.g.:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX oc_storages_pkey ON public.oc_storages USING btree (numeric_id);
ALTER TABLE public.oc_storages ADD CONSTRAINT oc_storages_pkey UNIQUE USING INDEX oc_storages_pkey;
```

If you do have such a table constraint already, then this would be a case of corruption.